# Are $A$ and $B$ disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets. If I prove that $a \notin B$ for all $a \in A$, can I say that $A \cap B = \emptyset$?

Comment: Prove by contradiction!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you prove that $a\in A \Rightarrow a\notin B$, then $A\subseteq B^c$, and that means $$A\cap B \subseteq B^c \cap B =\varnothing$$
so $A\cap B =\varnothing$.

Comment: Okey, good answer. Thank you very much.